# LP in standard form

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I don't know how to properly named this question but here it goes:

Let $x, c \in \Bbb{R}^n$, $b \in\Bbb{R}^m$, $A \in \Bbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Consider LP in the form:
min $\{c^tx : Ax = b, x \ge 0\}$

Let $N_c \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ be defined as a set of $\forall c \in \Bbb{R}^n $ for which the LP is solvable for fixed $A$ and $b$. Analogously define sets $N_b \subset \Bbb{R}^m$ and $N_A \subset \Bbb{R}^m \times \Bbb{R}^m \times...\Bbb{R}^m $.

Prove or contradict that:

a) $N_c$ is convex

b) $N_c$ is a convex cone pointed at $(0,0)$ or a linear subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$
c) $N_A$ is convex
d) For $A \neq 0$, $N_b$ has only one or only two points.

How can I describe an element of $N_c$ so that I would be able to prove that this set is convex? How about the description of $A$?

Many thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean, specifically, by "the LP is solvable"? Do you mean "the LP admits at least one finite optimal point"? Because I can "solve" an infeasible LP just fine by, say, finding a Farkas certificate proving it is infeasible.

Comment: That $\exists x \ge 0$ s.t. $Ax=b$

Comment: OK, but then in that case, what does $c$ have to do with it? That is either true or not true no matter what $c$ is.

Comment: What is true? There exists a limited number of c's which fulfils this criterion and the amount of c's depends on whether $Ax=b$ has a solution for such a c or not.

Comment: The set of solutions to $Ax=b$, $x\geq 0$ does not depend in any way on $c$. So by your definition of "solvable" (which really is just "feasible"), there are only two possibilities: if the set of solutions is non-empty $N_c\equiv\mathbb{R}^n$; otherwise, $N_c\equiv\emptyset$.

Comment: Now. If by "solvable" you also mean *bounded*, then indeed there are further restrictions on $c$. In that case I believe $N_c=\{c~|~c^Tx\geq 0~\forall~x\geq 0~\text{s.t}~Ax=0\}$ if the LP is feasible, and $N_c=\emptyset$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGrant. Indeed, I meant feasible and after some sketches I got what you wrote. In that case, $N_c$ is a linear subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$, am I right?